# Why layer.get_weights() is returning list of length 1 and 4?

Tags: list, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to get the weights and biases of all convolutional layers of `resnet50` model for one of my assignments. I learned that we can use the function `layer.get_weights()` to get the weight and bias. This will return a list of which contains two elements weight of the layer stored at layer.get_weights()[0] and the bias is stored at layer.get_weights()[1]. Here is the code which I used.

```
import tensorflow as to
import source   
from source import models
from source.utils.image import read_image_bgr, preprocess_image, resize_image
from source.utils.visualization import draw_box, draw_caption
from source.utils.colors import label_color
from source.models import retinanet
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from tensorflow import ConfigProto

import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
import keras
from keras.layers import Input,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,UpSampling2D, Activation, Dropout
from keras.models import Model


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-weight", "--weight_file", type=str,default="trained_model.h5",help="Path to the weights file")
ap.add_argument("-backbone", "--backbone", type=str, default="resnet50",help="Backbone model name")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


#fetching a tensorflow session
def get_session():
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    return tf.Session(config=config)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.keras.backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config)) 
keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.set_session(get_session())


model = str(args.get("weight_file", False))
backbone = str(args.get("backbone", False))
model = models.load_model(str(model), backbone_name=str(backbone))

#model is the resnet50 model
for layer in model.layers:
    print('layer name', layer.name)
    we = layer.get_weights()
    print('len(we)',len(we))
```

But in my case, I am getting length 1 for some of the cases and length 4 for other cases which is different from what it is expected. I am really confused at this point. If anybody has any idea and suggestions will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the full code (including model building) to understand the problem fully.

Comment: @thushv89 I have edited above. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_weights()` function returns both trainable and not trainable parameters of a layer. The BatchNormalization layer has 4 parameters, which explains the 4 length outputs (since Resnet blocks have batchnorm). As far as I am aware, ResNet models do not use the bias term in the convolutional layers because of the batchnorm, which would explain the length 1 outputs.

Comment: Agree with your answer. I also looked further in detail and analyzed the layers of the model. Looks like you are correct. Thanks.